# "fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory" while compiling HTK

Tags: c, makefile, htk

I'm getting the following issue when trying to run `make` on the [HTK library](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/docs/inst-nix.shtml):

```
(cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
  || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/william/speech/htk/HTK-3.4.1/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
In file included from HShell.h:40:0,
                 from HGraf.c:54:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'HGraf.o' failed
make[1]: *** [HGraf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/william/speech/htk/HTK-3.4.1/htk/HTKLib'
Makefile:96: recipe for target 'HTKLib/HTKLib.a' failed
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

I'm unsure what to do about this error. The `libc-header-start.h` file is present on my system:

```
$ find /usr -name libc-header-start.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
```

Running `gcc -H -fsyntax-only /usr/include/stdio.h` appropriately returns

```
. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
.. /usr/include/features.h
... /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
```

etc.

Also, compiling and running a sanity-check C file works fine (simply executing `printf("hello!");` in its main method).

Apologies if this is a well-known error - my experience with C libraries stops at compiling and installing them using `make`.

**UPDATE** 
Per the accepted answer below I executed `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` to install the missing 32 bit libraries.

Afterwards I got an error with a similar cause: `"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11" error when installing htk`. I resolved this by executing `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386 libx11-dev` to retrieve the missing 32 bit library.

Comment: Is this a 64 or 32 bit system? (i.e. what's the output of `uname -a`?)

Comment: The gcc invocation you show is `gcc  -m32`, which tells gcc to compile a 32-bit binary. For that purpose, it will not look for header files in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, because that directory (as hinted at by its name) contains headers for 64-bit builds.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The `-m32` is telling gcc to compile for a 32-bit platform. On a 64-bit platform, gcc normally only comes with 64-bit libraries. You have two options:

1. Install 32-bit headers and libraries. Here's how you'd do this on Ubuntu.

   Run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
   ```
2. Compile for 64-bit instead. Modify this line in the file named `configure`:

   ```
    CFLAGS="-m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH=\"$host_cpu\"' $CFLAGS"
   ```

   Delete `-m32`, giving you:

   ```
    CFLAGS="-ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH=\"$host_cpu\"' $CFLAGS"
   ```

   Run `./configure`, then `make clean`, then `make`

   However, I would recommend against this approach. The library authors went out of their way to make this build for 32 bits on a 64 bit system, and I can't guarantee that it will work correctly if you do this. (It does compile, though.)

Comment: **gcc-multilib** worked Thanks!

Comment: Tried  the first option "sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib" on Linux Mint 21.1 and worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 18):

Below is one way to debug and fix this issue. Since most linux installations differ in one way or another, YMMV.

1. Find which package installed `libc-header-start.h`.

```
$ dpkg -S libc-header-start.h
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h
```

On a working system, `/usr/include/bits` is a symlink to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits`. Running dpkg search gives us:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/bits
libc6-dev-i386: /usr/include/bits
```

Installing `libc6-dev-i386` creates the symlink and the error is addressed.

However, subsequently I ran into a linker error with the linker not being able to find libgcc (`-lgcc`). Apparently Linux default linker needs libgcc in most cases. Further debugging the issue with linker verbosity enabled lead me to missing `lib32gcc-10-dev` package.

**In short, unless a very controlled build environment is desired, just install `gcc-multilib` package when using `-m32` (needed for `gcc` or  `clang`). For C++, `g++-multilib` is also required.**

Comment: I ran into a python2.7 binary, in an android repo on a Centos rel 8 machine, which bash was unable to run. Running `file`, `objdump`, and `ldd` on the binary showed dynamic linkage and a 32 bit elf. Resolved by `sudo dnf install glibc.i686`.