# HTK 32bit issue -> apt-get install gcc-multilib -> "Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate"

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, htk

I am trying to install HTK. I tried ./configure, and received an error on `make all`:

```
cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \
  || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pranay/HTK-3.4.1/htk/HTKLib'
gcc  -m32 -ansi -D_SVID_SOURCE -DOSS_AUDIO -D'ARCH="x86_64"' -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o HGraf.o HGraf.c
In file included from HShell.h:40,
                 from HGraf.c:54:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
```

So I searched this issue, and found ["fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory" while compiling HTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082459/fatal-error-bits-libc-header-start-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-compili#). This led to the following solution `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`. However, this gives another issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-multilib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate
```

I was unable to find a proper solution after this point. I could try to remove -m32 from the file originally, but apparently this is not the proper way and could lead to more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem adding the following line in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

After, install gcc-multilib with apt:

```
#apt install gcc-multilib
```

Comment: This can seriously break your system if you aren't on Debian Sid, there are ways to safely install packages from other repos, but this isn't one of them

Comment: please tell me how...

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo apt install aptitude

sudo aptitude -y install gcc-multilib
```

worked on Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc version 7.5