# error bundling pyaudio package in android apk for ARM

Tags: android, github-actions, pyaudio

For using SpeechRecognition package we need pyaudio package. To bundle it in an apk (to deploy and use it on android), it needs to be installed using pip. There are 3 ways (local linux, google colab, GitHub action) for deploying python apps on android as detailed in https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-convert-python-app-into-apk-77f4c9cd55af

I tried first and third (please refer https://github.com/sameermahajan/PaadasML) options without any luck. I run into the exact same error on both the systems as

```
/usr/include/limits.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
34939  #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
34940           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
34941  1 error generated.
34942  error: command '/usr/bin/ccache' failed with exit code 1
34943  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
34944  
34945  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
34946  │ exit code: 1
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
34954Failed to build pyaudio
34955ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Note that I need to do it for ARM

I had opened an issue of ['bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found error installing pyaudio in buildozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76216607/bits-libc-header-start-h-file-not-found-error-installing-pyaudio-in-buildozer) for this earlier. But it has a long comments thread there which might be confusing hence opening this new issue with the latest summary in case it helps.